# Traveling salesman neighborhood

Tags: combinatorics, algorithms, computer-science

I am solving some TSP problems and i got this one and i am not pretty sure about my answer.

By seeing TSP as a formal combinatorial problem, i have that the Feasible solutions $F$ is the set defined as $F=\{S\subseteq V^2:S \text{ a hamiltonial circuit}\}$, with some cost function associated to the sum of the weights. Now, by defining the neighborhood of a feasible solution $f$ as $N_k(f)$ to be the feasible solutions $g$ such that $g$ is obtained from $f$ by deleting $k$ edges from $f$ and adding another $k$ edges. I am asked to count the number of elements of $N_2(f)$ and $N_3(f)$.

For $N_2(f)$ there are $2$ options, or either i remove the edges and put the same edges obtaining $f$ or i remove the edges and i cross the edges and it is just one way to do it, so:$$|N_2(t)|=\binom{n}{2}+1$$

Now, in the case where $k=3$, i have 4 options:

1. I take out the $3$ edges and i put the same edges. $1$
2. I take out the $3$ edges and i put back just one of them. $\binom{n}{3}\binom{3}{1}$
3. I take out the $3$ edges and i put back two of them, but then the third one just have 1 chance and i fall into case 1. $0$
4. I take out the $3$ edges and i do not put back any of them. $\binom{n}{3}d_3$(where $d_3$ is the derrangament number in $S_3$)

So $|N_3(t)|=\binom{n}{3}(\binom{3}{1}+d_3)+1$

My question is: am i overcounting some configurations? I have that feeling.

If i am not, a generalization would be $$|N_k(t)|=1+\binom{n}{k}\sum _{i=0}^{k-2}\binom{k}{i}d_{k-i}??$$

Thanks in advance.

Comment: In the case $N_2(f)$, what happens if the edges you remove are incident, e.g. you remove $(v_i, v_j)$ and $(v_k, v_j)$, will not swapping the enpoints here result in $(v_i, v_j)$ and $(v_k, v_j)$, i.e. the same configuration you started with?

Comment: @Calle Thanks for reading, i think we can not have that situation because it is a hamiltonian circuit. We can not have two arrows pointing to the same vertex.

Comment: Right, each vertex has only two edges connected to it. But if you want to be able to get each possible "swap of two edges" in your argument above, don't you need to view each edge both as $(v_i, v_j)$ and $(v_j, v_i)$?

Comment: @Calle I do not take that into account because it is a directed path. I do not see why i must take the two edges in a feasible solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the case $k=2$ either you removed two adjacent edges (this can be done in $n$ ways) or not (this can be done in $\binom{n}{2}-n$ ways). If you removed two adjacent edges you still get $f$ after completing the cycle. Else you can get a new feasible cycle by inserting two crossing edges (as you noticed). Thus we have $|N_2(f)|=\binom{n}{2}-n+1$. The following table summarizes the counts:

$$
\begin{array}{c|c|cr}
\text{Remove} & \text{n. of possible removals} & \text{n. of new cycles from each removal} \\
\hline
\text{2 adjacent} & n  & 0 \\
\text{0 adjacent} & \binom{n}{2}-n  & 1
\end{array}
$$

For the case $k=3$ the table is:

$$
\begin{array}{c|c|cr}
\text{Remove} & \text{n. of possible removals} & \text{n. of new cycles from each removal} \\
\hline
\text{3 adjacent} & n  & 1 \\
\text{2 adjacent} & n(n-4)  & 1\\
\text{0 adjacent} & \binom{n}{3}-n-n(n-4)  & 1
\end{array}
$$

In fact, consider removing three adjacent edges, say $v_1,v_2,v_3$. You can obtain only one "new" feasible cycle (i.e. $\neq$f) by reinserting $v_2$ and then connecting vertex 1 with 3 and vertex 2 with vertex 4. Similarly, consider removing two adjacent edges and then a third non-adjacent one. This can be done by first choosing two adjacent edges (in $n$ ways) and then choosing one more edge among the $n-4$ non-adjacent ones. Now connect the extremes of the larger hole and the left-alone vertex to the extremes of the smaller hole to obtain a new feasible cycle. Finally, from the table we have $|N_3(f)|=\binom{n}{3}+1$.

On the bibliographic side, this is exercise 5 in Ch.1 of *Combinatorial Optimization: algorithms and complexity* by C.H. Papadimitriou and K. Steiglitz, Dover Publications. I think it is a reference on this topic but as far as I can see there are no solutions to the exercises.